# How can I replace Kong Error to a custom text?

Tags: kong

Kong Error

API rate limit exceeded.

How Can I replace the Kong Error to a custom text for example "PoC Error"?

Comment: I did a PR to implement it https://github.com/Kong/kong/pull/8930

Comment: The PR has been approved

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not ideal but for now it is working until a better solution (maybe from kong) comes up. The problem with custom error messages exists with all plugins and internals.

I have created a global post-function ([serverless-functions](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/serverless-functions/#main)) which checks if a status code is above 400 and intercepts the response.

A static defined table with all errors to intercept is defined at the top of the post-function "body-phase" handler.

The problem is that kong errors not always looks the same, because they generate the error message by looking at the "Content-Type" header from response.
My solution is to take the same util they took for template generation ([kong.utils](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/kong/tools/utils.lua#L1248)) and populate my error table with different messages.

First, in the post-function "header-phase", i check the response code. If it is above 400 i clear the "Content-Length" header (required) and set a flag (for example kong.ctx.custom_error) for next phase to indicate interception is required.

Second, in the post-function "body-phase", i check for the flag and match the response body against my generated error-table. If a match is found the response body will be overwritten with the predefined error message.

For performance considerations i memoized the table in the "body-phase" by returning the handler for overwriting the body to kong. For now kong will generate the table once on load and if a request occurs only the returned function will be invoked.

hope that I could explain it to some extent and it helps further